# Probability of not Drawing 5 Kings

Tags: probability

A special deck of cards just contains the face cards (jack, queen, king) of each suit. What is the probability that you draw:

A hand of five cards in which you have no kings?

My Attempt: $(1-4/12)(1-3/11)(1-2/10)(1-1/9)(1) = 4096/11880$

Answer: $14/99$

Comment: The title sounds like you want the probability of drawing 5 kings. You should probably edit it.

Comment: and there are only 4 kings in the deck

Answer (score 1):

That isn't quite right. You seem to be trying to find the probability of getting zero kings by multiplying the following probabilities:

1. the probability of not getting a king on the first card
2. the probability of not getting a king on the second card given that we didn't get a kind on the first card
3. the probability of not getting a king on the third card given that we didn't get a kind on the first or second card
4. the probability of not getting a king on the fourth card given that we didn't get a kind on the first, second, or third card
5. the probability of not getting a king on the fifth card given that we didn't get a kind on the first, second, third, or fourth card

Indeed, the probability of not getting a king on the first card is $1-\tfrac{4}{12}$, as you have written. However, once you draw a non-king on the first card, there are still $4$ kings left in the deck of $11$ remaining cards. So the 2nd probability should be $1-\tfrac{4}{11}$ not $1-\tfrac{3}{11}$.

If you use similar reasoning for the remaining probabilities, you will get $(1-\tfrac{4}{12})(1-\tfrac{4}{11})(1-\tfrac{4}{10})(1-\tfrac{4}{9})(1-\tfrac{4}{8}) = \tfrac{7}{99}$ as the answer.

You can also get this answer quicker using the method in Derek Luna's answer, i.e. the probability is $\dfrac{\# \ \text{ways to choose 5 non-kings}}{\# \ \text{ways to choose 5 cards}} = \dfrac{\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \dfrac{7}{99}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hands with no Kings: $8 \choose 5$ ($8$ cards to choose from that are not kings)

Total Hands: $12 \choose 5$

So the probability to get a hand with no Kings is
$8 \choose 5$$/$$12 \choose 5$$ = 7/99$